# Splitting when meeting another alphabet

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, multilingual, alphabet

Let say I have a string:

```
欧珑 无极乌龙 Atelier Cologne Oolang Infini, 2010
```

How can I split it in a array of two strings? `['欧珑 无极乌龙','Atelier Cologne Oolang Infini, 2010']`

I tried:

```
names = re.split(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', names)
```

But it gave:

```
names:  ['欧珑 无极乌龙 ', 'Atelier', ' ', 'Cologne', ' ', 'Oolang', ' ', 'Infini', ', 2010']
```

Comment: So, `欧珑 无极乌龙 Atelier Cologne Oolang Infini, 2010 И я тебя люблю` would yield `['欧珑 无极乌龙', 'Atelier Cologne Oolang Infini, 2010', 'И я тебя люблю']`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Excatly

Comment: What is the rule that tells you when one substring stops and the next starts?

Comment: Look carefully at your desired output. I assume your plan is that `'Atelier Cologne Oolang Infini, 2010'` is treated as the "separator" that you're splitting on, splitting `'欧珑 无极乌龙'` apart from an empty string at the end. But... does `[a-zA-Z]+` describe that separator?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for pushing me through, I also tried to get `[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+` but that separates the Chinese characters in two `['欧珑', ' ', '无极乌龙', ' Atelier Cologne Oolang Infini', ',', ' 2010', '']`

Comment: What about `re.split(r'\s*((?!\s)[\W\d_]*[A-Za-z].*?[A-Za-z][\W\d_]*?)\s*(?=(?![a-zA-Z])[^\W\d_]|$)', text)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh, man. Let me _prendre un cours de regex avec vous_. You seem like a Regex God.

Comment: The regex just breaks texts that are separated with "English" text. If the English part is at the end, and Chinese and Russian are at the start, the RU and ZH parts won't get separated.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Just for the sake of knowing, what about French? Or Polish?

Comment: That is already a non-regex domain.

Comment: If you need something simple for distinguish between latin and non-latin parts, maybe you would suffice with something like [`(?i)(?:[^a-z\d]+|[a-z\d\W]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/qpCUlC/2) [see this demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYsrLzE3tVjBVkH92Zrlz/snKjybvuDZvMYnO3te7pup4FiSmpOZWqTgnJ@Tn56XquCfn5OYl67gmZeWmZepo2BkYGigjjCiKFUPKJ6SmJOjUaSuYZ@pqWFvFR2XqFsVkxKrXRMNZsSEx2prqusogPVocnEVFGXmlWjAeP//AwA).

Comment: Since teh question is closed, I can't add an answer, but briefly: I would use the regex module and the unicodedataplus module to identify the set of scripts (excluding Common and Inherited) in the string, generate a regex pattern based on the scripts, then do a regex split on the string. So for a string with a CJK run and Latin run, the generated regex pattern is: ([\p{Latin}][\p{Latin}\p{Common}\p{Inherited}]*|[\p{Han}][\p{Han}\p{Common}\p{Inherited}]*). Some cleanup of the string may be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

A quick simple regex for distinguishing between *latin* and *non-latin* parts ([regex101 **demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qpCUlC/3)).

```
(?i)[^a-z\d]+|[_a-z\d\W]+
```

Use with `re.findall` ([tio.run **demo**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYsrLzE3tVjBVkH92Zrlz/snKjybvuDZvMYnO3te7pup4FiSmpOZWqTgnJ@Tn56XquCfn5OYl67gmZeWmZepo2BkYGigjjCiKFUPKJ6SmJOjUaSuYZ@pGR2XqFsVkxKrXRMNZsSEx2qr6yiA1WtycRUUZeaVaMB4//8DAA)). The regex is pretty self explaining and matches

- either `[^a-z\d]+` [one or more](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#quantifiers) characters, that are [not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) latin alphabetic or digits
- or `[_a-z\d\W]+` one or more, that are `_` latin alphas, digits or *non-[word-characters](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#chars)*

It's fast, but you need to trim whitespace from the result. Else it gets more complicated : ) To **distinguish** *latin* / *non-latin* in the result, you can use [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) with [groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) ([tio.run **demo**](https://tio.run/##ZY6xSgNBEIb7fYrxEHaXJEdyFoGAiFhZWVrkVDZm7xy4m13WEVRs7AWxEhuxS@ML2FjkWeTEpzg3QZHEqWZ@5v/@31/xmaOttsXau8AQrBBsLxm2QZrJKTSvs8/7B2geX5rn24@3u6/3J9hlW6ENsOcqV5KFA1cZKmGfCiTsQtYf9FcNG8l8tgmFczAxYTiUwhtmG2gRonZQq/Gx6V3n06OOvlHjk@WeH8ZLClG4ADUgxWZp5E8xGtWPvwuLqnokALBQdVoGd@HVQC8VAB@QWCXkqFcZRhrlLBPowN9jes4BvdJRTGSiVznZGueXsUbJ/lHitO03)).

```
import re

text = '欧珑 无极乌龙 Atelier Cologne Oolang Infini, 2010 乌龙乌 foo$'
pattern = '(?i)([^a-z\d]+)|([_a-z\d\W]+)'

for m in re.finditer(pattern, text):
  if(m.group(1)):
    print("non-latin:\t'" + m.group(1).strip() + "'")
  if(m.group(2)):
    print("latin:\t\t'" + m.group(2).strip() + "'")
```